# Compiling multiple packages in same folder in ROS

Tags: cmake, command-line-interface, ubuntu-16.04, ros, catkin

I have 4 separate packages:

1. https://github.com/catkin/catkin_simple
2. https://github.com/ethz-asl/glog_catkin
3. https://github.com/ethz-asl/asctec_mav_framework
4. https://github.com/ethz-asl/ethzasl_msf

I saved them in a master folder and tried compiling them using catkin_make and got the following cmake error:
CMake Error at devel/share/glog_catkin/cmake/glog_catkinConfig.cmake:148 (message):

```
  Project 'msf_core' tried to find library 'glog'.  The library is neither a
  target nor built/installed properly.  Did you compile project
  'glog_catkin'? Did you find_package() it before the subdirectory containing
  its code is included?
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:76 (find_package)
  ethzasl_msf/msf_core/CMakeLists.txt:17 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/yukti/Desktop/MSF_PACKAGE/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/yukti/Desktop/MSF_PACKAGE/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Invoking "cmake" failed
```

So I tried compiling them individually. After compiling one of them and trying to compile the others, I got the following error:

```
CMake Error: The source "/home/yukti/Desktop/MSF_PACKAGE/asctec_mav_framework-master/CMakeLists.txt" does not match the source "/home/yukti/Desktop/MSF_PACKAGE/catkin_simple-master/CMakeLists.txt" used to generate cache.  Re-run cmake with a different source directory.
Invoking "cmake" failed
```

Another thing I tried was creating multiple folders that individually stored each package and compiling them. I still failed to make it work.

I am having trouble determining if I need to create multiple catkin workspaces or try overlaying them or if there is a simpler solution to the problem.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Placing multiple packages inside a workspace is possible and a fundamental approach in ROS.

The error

> Project 'msf_core' tried to find library 'glog'.

tells that the glog library is needed to compile but missing. Check out [How to install and use GLog](https://codeyarns.com/2017/10/26/how-to-install-and-use-glog/) and install glog like

```
sudo apt install libgoogle-glog-dev
```

After installing the library compilation should be possible.